# Bounty section for a user's profile is naked and drunk

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, bounties

On a user's account summary page, the bounty section seems to have lost it's header styling, and doesn't seem to work very cooperatively; it seems to work on the first instance, but further attempts to change it won't work.

> [image]

I'm on Chrome 37.0.2062.120. Tried clearing caches etc. with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed and it will be out in the next build (#2568)

Comment: Wow... that was quick :).