# "Active bounties" section on user profiles page is borked

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, bounties

The "Active Bounties" section on the user profile page is currently in a font totally different from all the other ones. The awesome-style selection menu has also been converted into an ugly, unstyled combo box.

This looks pretty ugly and should be fixed.

Comment: @Jehof Yes; sorry; didn't see that as the search duplicate thing on the ask questions page did not bring up the other question.

Comment: There was also [Bounty section for a user's profile is naked and drunk](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239446), posted minutes before yours.